# How to read a csv file by eliminating the newline character?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, newline

I have a csv file in the format:

```
       text                    label 
it was incredible!!            1
the politician was exhausted     0
'and so was little Sebastian!'   0
```

I am trying reading it using pandas:

```
train = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", header = 0, delimiter = "\t", quoting = 3)
print(train.shape)
```

Printing the shape of train gives me double the number of lines orignally present in the csv file.
The problem I found is that the alternate lines in the data frame `train` are being split by newline character so that `train["text"][0]` gives:

> "it was incredible!!"

`train["text"][1]` gives:

> "

Similar is the result for every alternate line pairs thus resulting in the double of original size. I figured out the possible reason for it could be that before writing my list of tuples, i.e. `mylist = [(text, '1'), (text, '0')..]` to the csv file, printing `mylist[0]` gives:

> ('it was incredible \n', '1')

Similarly, mylist[2] would give:

> (" 'and so was little Sebastian! '\n", '0')

i.e. a '\n' is somehow appended at the end of each text. Is there any way to prevent these line splits by eliminating '\n' character?

Comment: You're right that the problem is with *writing* the file, not with reading it. Fix the problem there (using `rstrip()`.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will give you an idea:

```
test = "hi \n"
print test
print test[:-1]
```

With [:-1] you can slice the last character

Comment: Don't. You have enough of a mess in your hands already. Use `rstrip()` instead (or `rstrip("\n")` if you have some trailing whitespace you do want to keep).

Comment: Brute. What if your last character is not `'\n'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the last character using `[:-1]`:

```
line = 'x,y,z\n'
print line[:-1] # Out: x,y,z
```

Or replace `'\n'` with `''`:

```
line = line.replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want might be to strip your train data from any trailing newline characters, which can be done for strings with the Python string method rstrip:

```
.rstrip('\n')
```

Similarly for pandas timeseries the method is:

```
pandas.Series.str.strip()
```

(See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)